# Speed up the Probability-Weighted Sampling in R

Tags: r, performance, multicore, sample, weighted

How can I speed up **probability-weighted** Sampling in R.

```
# Let's assume we are considering following example:
w <- sample(1:4000,size=2e6, replace=T)   

# "w" will be integer, so we are going to convert it to numeric.
w <- as.numeric(w)

# Actually the sampling process have to be repeated many times.
M <- matrix(NA, 10, 2000)
system.time(
for (r in 1:10){
  ix <- sample(1:2e6,size=2000,prob=w/sum(w))
  M[r,] <- ix
})
# It's worth it to mention that without "prob=w/sum(w)" sampling is considerably faster.
# The main goal is to speed up sampling with probability weights!
system.time(ix <- sample(1:2e6,size=2000,prob=w/sum(w)))
```

A weighted sampling takes 9.84 sec., normal sampling 0.01 sec.
If you have any idea how it is possible to speed up *weighted sampling*, please feel open to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The speed problem is only limited to weighted sampling without replacement.  Here's your code again, moving the parts unrelated to `sample` outside of the loop.

```
normalized_weights <- w/sum(w)
#No weights
system.time(
for (r in 1:10){
  ix <- sample(2e6, size = 2000)
})
#Weighted, no replacement
system.time(
for (r in 1:10){
  ix <- sample(2e6, size = 2000, prob = normalized_weights)
})
#Weighted with replacement
system.time(
for (r in 1:10){
  ix <- sample(2e6, size = 2000, replace = TRUE, prob = normalized_weights)
})
```

The big problem is that when you do weighted sampling without replacement, each time you pick a value, the weights need to be recalculated.  See `?sample`:

> If 'replace' is false, these probabilities are applied sequentially,
>   that is the probability of choosing the next item is proportional to
>   the weights amongst the remaining items.

There may be faster solutions than using `sample` (I don't know how well it's been optimized) but it's a fundamentally more computationally intensive task than the unweighted/weighted-with-replacement sampling.

Comment: Weights don't need to be normalized for `sample`.

Comment: @Roland True, `sample` will do the normalising itself.  (Indeed it does it lots of times for weighted sampling without replacement.)  I was trying to let sample do the least work possible for the purposese of testing the speed.